# What's the "condition" in C interview test?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Would it be possible to print `Hello` twice using single `condition`?

```
if  "condition"
  printf ("Hello");
else
  printf("World");
```

Comment: [http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/65997](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/65997)

Comment: I mean what should be code in 'if' condition if we want to execute code in both the blocks??

Comment: Show the code so we can have a look.

Comment: @Michael This question was asked for an interview, I told the same..but the guy on other side said that you can do that in C.

Comment: This is a stupid trick question. The question probably was more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199/whats-the-condition-in-c-interview-question and the answers are there.

Comment: The answer is: you don't want to work somewhere that asks stupid questions like that.

Comment: I wish someone would explain to me why this is downvoted and meant to be closed? because it's not a particularly good interview question? since when are we SO snobbish?

Comment: @eliben - it says clearly it was closed as an 'exact duplicate' - with a reference to a possible question that asks something similar.

Comment: Duplicate? I think not! Most of the answers in the "duplicate" are not as interesting as the answers here. Partly because the question is *completely different*. Here we want to execute both branches, in the other question the requirement was to create a condition that caused a certain output. Very different questions with very different answers. One is testing your knowledge of goto-like constructs, the other is testing your awareness of side effects in conditions.

Comment: And for bonus marks, do it in a way that conforms to MISRA C coding standards.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
if ( printf("Hello") == 0 )
    printf ("Hello");
else
    printf ("World");
```

:-)

Comment: For printf: On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

Answer (score 21):

```
"condition" === (printf("Hello"), 0)
```

Really lame:

```
int main() {
    if  (printf("Hello"), 0)
        printf ("Hello");
    else
        printf("World");
}
```

I prefer the use of the comma operator because you don't have to look up the return value of `printf` in order to know what the conditional does. This increases readability and maintainability. :-)

Answer (score 17):

This sounds to me like some interview puzzle. I hope this is close to what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 static int i = 0 ;
 if( i++==0 ? main(): 1)
  printf("Hello,");
 else
  printf("World\n");

 return 0 ;
}
```

prints `Hello, World`

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It doesn't use forks so the order is guaranted and also doesn't print "Hello" in the condition. The execution actually enters in the two decisions branches... Otherwise, you could print everything in the condition and then end the program, I think that is not a very clever solution!

Answer (score 13):

Buckle your seatbelts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int main()
{
    jmp_buf env;

    if (!setjmp(env))
    {
        printf("if executed\n");
        longjmp(env, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("else executed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
if executed
else executed
```

Is this what you mean? I doubt it, but at least it's possible. Using `fork` you can do it also, but the branches will run in different processes.

Comment: Beware: you cannot portably assign the return value from the setjmp() macro.

Comment: @jonathan -  you're right, fixed the code. However, I wonder whether there's any compiler these days that doesn't handle it correctly. Many C "exception" frameworks based on setjmp use its return value saved to a flag

Comment: In practice, it probably works; I certainly don't know of a platform where it doesn't work - but I've not investigated either, because debugging the failure would be painful (at best).  Assigning the return value of `setjmp()` is undefined behaviour; anything could happen (including 'it works as expected or desired').

Answer (score 11):

If it is on Unix:

```
if  (fork())
    printf ("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

Ofcoures that doesn't guarantee the order 0f the prints

Answer (score 6):

The `if` statement executes one or the other of the controlled statements (both `printf` in your example). No matter what you use for `condition`, that snippet will either print "Hello", or "World", but never both.

Edit: Okay, so it's a trick question and you can put whatever you like in the condition (including a call to an entire other function that does anything you want). But that's hardly interesting. I can't believe I got downmodded for giving a correct answer.

Comment: I can't believe it either, whoever did it in my view was petty/lame. So here is some rep back :) There shouldn't be negative penalties for not being "clever" enough to see the solution and posting what you genuinely thought was correct.

Answer (score 6):

```
#define CONDITION (0) if (0) {} else
```

or some such.

If you see such a question on an interview, run away as fast as you can! The team that asks such questions is bound to be unhealthy.

Edit - I forgot to clarify - this relies on "else" being matched with closest open "if", and on the fact that it's written as "if CONDITION" rather than if (CONDITION) - parenthesis would make the puzzle unsolvable.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( printf("Hello")==0)
```

see
[http://www.coders2020.com/what-does-printf-return]

(matt corrected my =, thanks, C is far away)

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the return value of `printf` off the top of your head:

```
if (printf("Hello") && 0)
    printf("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

Answer (score 3):

Comment the "else" ;)

```
if(foo)
{
    bar();
}
//else
{
    baz();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Good use of comment.

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is that in the ordinary course of events you neither want to execute both the statements in the 'if' block and the 'else' block in a single pass through the code (why bother with the condition if you do) nor can you execute both sets of statements without jumping through grotesque hoops.

Some grotesque hoops - evil code!

```
    if (condition == true)
    {
         ...stuff...
         goto Else;
    }
    else
    {
Else:
        ...more stuff...
    }
```

Of course, it is a plain abuse of (any) language because it is equivalent to:

```
    if (condition == true)
    {
         ...stuff...
    }
    ...more stuff...
```

However, it might achieve what the question is asking.  If you have to execute both blocks whether the condition is true or false, then things get a bit trickier.

```
    done_then = false;
    if (condition == true)
    {
Then:
         ...stuff...
         done_then = true;
         goto Else;
    }
    else
    {
Else:
        ...more stuff...
        if (!done_then) goto Then;
    }
```

Comment: An 'even more evil' version of the code reverses the labels (so the 'then' clause has a label 'Else' and vice versa).  And maybe the 'ultimate' in evil-ness insists that the code blocks are executed in the same order regardless of the result of the condition (which can be done, of course).  But the requirements are then getting so far-fetched as to be ridiculous - if they weren't already!

Comment: As far as I think he asked for a condition,not for a "goto" in the statement,broke that rule in my sense

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    runIfElse(true);
    runIfElse(false);

    return 0;
}

void runIfElse(bool p)
{
    if(p)
    {
     // do if
    }
    else
    {
     // do else
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the question means by 'run', is it?  +1 for distorting the question a different way.

Answer (score 2):

```
if  (true) printf ("Hello"); if (false)
    printf ("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

Answer (score 2):

No love for `exit`?

```
if(printf("HelloWorld"), exit(0), "ByeBye") 
    printf ("Hello");
else
    printf ("World");
```

Answer (score 2):

So... you want to execute the code inside the if block... and the code inside of the else block... of the same if/else statement?  Then... you should get rid of the else and stick taht code in the if.

```
if something
  do_this
  do_that
end
```

The else statement is designed to execute only if the if statement is not executed and vice-versa, that is the whole point.  This is an odd question...

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
if (printf("Hello") - strlen("Hello"))
    printf("Hello")
else
    printf("World")
```

This snippet emphasizes the return value of `printf`: The number of characters printed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    if( argc == 2 || main( 2, NULL ) )
    {
        printf("Hello ");   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("World\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2 (Only for Unix and Linux):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    if( !fork() )
    {
        printf("Hello ");   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("World\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code before or after the if..else block.

Alternatively, if you have an "if, else if, else" block where you want to execute code in some (but not all) branches, just put it in a separate function and call that function within each block.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
{
 if(! printf("Hello"))
     printf ("Hello");
else
    printf ("World");
 return 0;
}
```

Because Printf returns the number of character it has printed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Abuse of preprocessing - with cleanup at least.

```
#define else 
if(1)
{
   printf("hello");
}
else
{
   printf("world");
}
#undef else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(printf("Hello") == 1)
    printf("Hello")
else
    printf("World")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (printf("Hello") < 1)
    printf("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Greg wrote:
>
> > No matter what you use for condition, that snippet will either print "Hello", or "World", but never both.

Well, this isn't true, but why you would *want* it to print both, I can't find a use case for. It's defeating the point of having an if statement. The likely "real" solution is to not use an if at all. Silly interview questions... :)

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting guys, thanks for the answers. I never would have thought about putting the print statement inside the if condition.

Here's the Java equivalent:

```
    if ( System.out.printf("Hello").equals("") )
        System.out.printf("Hello");
    else
        System.out.printf("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use an if else block then.

EDIT to Comment.

It might then mean that the code be in both blocks, or before/after the block if it is required to run in both cases.

Comment: what should be code in 'if' condition if we want to execute code in both the blocks??

Answer (score 0):

use a goto, one of the single most underused keywords of our day

Comment: And quite possibly one of the most dangerous, as Dijkstra and others have mentioned.

Comment: goto isn't nearly as dangerous as the array dereference operator.

Answer (score 0):

Cheeting with an empty else statement:

```
if (condition)
    // do if stuff
else;
    // do else stuff
```

If you don't like the fact that else; is actually an empty else statement try this:

```
for (int ii=0; ii<2; ii++)
{
    if (condition && !ii)
        // do if stuff
    else
    {
        // do else stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible Solutions without using printf statements :-

First :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
  if (!stdin || (stdin = 0, main()))
    printf("hello");
  else
    printf("world");
  return 0;
}
```

Second

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
if (1
#define else if (1) 
)
{ 
  printf("hello"); 
} 
else
 { 
    printf("world"); 
}
}
```

Reference :- [Link1](http://ideone.com/q5Y7j) , [Link2](http://codepad.org/qfS5my7p)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (printf("hello") & 0)
{
printf("hello");
}
else
{
printf("world");
```

No need to bother about the return value of printf.

Answer (score -2):

The condition to this question is:

```
 if(printf("hello")? 0 : 1) {   }
```

Comment: if(printf("hello")? 0 : 1)
    {}
    else printf("world");