# Simultaneous execution of both if and else blocks

Tags: c++, c, conditional-statements

In C or C++

```
if ( x )
    statement1;
else
    statement2;
```

For what value of `x` will both statements be executed?

I know we can execute `if-else` together like this:

```
if(1){
    goto ELSE;
}
else{
    ELSE:
}
```

Is there any way, like a value? 
(Which I think is not possible. Asking because someone is arguing!)

Comment: Not possible for if/else, but possible if you rewrite it to a switch and omit `break`

Comment: A bool expression can be false, true and UB.  UB can whack the stack, anything is possible.

Comment: It's kind of possible if you use preprocessor macros to redefine `if` and `else` to something different. It's possible you get shot by your coworkers if you do that, too.

Comment: The entire point of an if statement is to execute one branch or another. A boolean expression is either true or false, so you go in one or the either, period.

Comment: There is a possibility that the `true` condition may execute code *common* to both statement blocks within the `else` statement block.  This is the compiler refactoring the code.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Thomas: How a compiler might choose to implement some certain code isn't really related to executing both blocks, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> for what value of x both statements will be executed?

There is no such value: either the value evaluates to `true` (something != 0), or it evaluates to `false`) (0). No other possible values exist.

> I know we can execute if-else together like this: if(1){ goto ELSE; } else{ ELSE: }

That works but it isn’t depending of the value of the `if` condition at all.

Comment: I don't know if C/C++ allows this but perhaps you should expand your first part of the answer to cover what happens if an expression could evaluate to both, for instance in C#, operator overloads could make a value correspond to both true and false, depending on the expression it was used in, but this still wouldn't lead to both branches executing.

Comment: fork() is the answer (see SigTerm's answer).

Comment: It's not possible to evaluate both statements without essentially removing the if, since there's no point in having an if if both the if and the else are executed- that's called regular code.

Comment: @Paul: how does `fork` change what I’ve said? Yes, it’s a pretty cute trick but it does not invalidate my statement.

Comment: @Lasse: my answer is *very* incomplete. In fact, C++ also allows a similar (but *not quite* the same) behaviour: you can create an implicit conversion operator which would more or less correspond to C#’ `true` operator, you can overload the `!` operator, and you can actually overload `&&` and `||` – albeit losing the short-circuiting on the way – but I felt that it would confuse more than do good so I intentionally left this out.

Comment: fork() is not available in my Windows C++ environment.

Answer (score 25):

> for what value of x both statements will be executed??

Only in this case (on unix-like systems):

```
 pid_t  pid;
 pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0){
    //some code
 }
 else {
    //some code
 }
```

In this case both branches will be always called simultaineously (well, more or less simultaneously), but in different processes.

> I know we can execute if-else together like this:

This:

```
if(1){
    goto ELSE;
}
else{
    ELSE:
}
```

is a wrong construct. You need to use something like this instead:

```
if ( condition) {
    //some code here
    ...
}
... //some other code here
```

If one branch is always called, then you don't need "else".

Comment: The fork is a nice trick, but does not really work with "one" value since the return value of fork() is zero for one and non zero for the other process.

Comment: The construct is only wrong though because there is a statement missing after `ELSE:`. If you replace it by `ELSE: ;` it becomes completely legal.

Comment: There is a possibility that the `true` condition may execute code *common* to both statement blocks within the `else` statement block.  This is the compiler refactoring the code.  See my answer below.

Comment: "When you come to a fork in the road, take it" -- Yogi Berra

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind some undefined behavior, you can do it like this in C++:

```
struct J {
  jmp_buf b;
};

struct backer {
  backer(int v):did(v) { }

  backer(backer const& o):j(o.j),did(o.did) { 
    o.did = true; 
  }

  ~backer() {
    if(!did) {
      longjmp(j.b, 1);
    }
  }

  operator bool() {
    return !did;
  }

  J j;
  mutable bool did;
};

int main() {
  if(backer b = setjmp(b.j.b)) {
    std::cout << "a";
  } else {
    std::cout << "b";
  }
}
```

This works fine with GCC and Clang. It works by calling `setjmp` on the buffer in `b.j.b`. That buffer is kept wrapped in a class because it can be an array, and arrays can only be copied if they are wrapped in a class. `backer`'s constructor then takes `setjmp`'s return value and initializes `did` with it. In `backer`'s destructor that flag is tested and if it's false (first return of `setjmp`), it jumps back and let `setjmp` return a non-zero value. The destructor of `backer` is called when one of the branches finish.

The compiler is free to copy the `backer` object constructed in initializing `b`. If that happens, the copy constructor of it cares about setting `did` to `true`, ensuring that we jump back only one time even if the compiler didn't optimize out the `backer` copy during initialization.

Thus the program prints `ab`.

Comment: That's different to the GOTO method how, precisely?

Comment: @DeadMG it doesn't change what the statement is. The Statements can be arbitrary. For the goto method, the statement has to have a goto at the end and the statement must be braced-enclosed as a result. So, the question asks "For what value x" but not "For what value x and what statements" - it doesn't allow changing the statements. The history of my answer shows that i first came up with an answer very similar to @John's current one - but i deleted it temporarily because i came to the conclusion it wasn't according to the rules :)

Answer (score 2):

In a recursive function both branches can be executed:

```
void recursive(bool first)
{
    if(first)
    {
        recursive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        //END
    }
}
```

Invoking it with

```
recursive(true)
```

will execute the if branch followed by the else branch

Answer (score 1):

First off, this isn't a stupid question :)

To understand why you can't accomplish this with any special trickery, we need to step down to the assembly that gets generated by an if-statement (particularly, the assembly for an Intel processor with gcc 4.2.1 -- different architectures will result in different assembly).

Take this simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i == 8)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

If the user enters a non-zero integer, we return 100; otherwise we return 3.  The actual condition doesn't really matter here, because we're only interested in the assembly generated for `main`:

```
        ; ...
        call    _scanf
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cmpl    $8, %eax
        jne     L2
        movl    $100, -20(%rbp)
        jmp     L4
L2:
        movl    $3, -20(%rbp)
L4:
        movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
        leave
        ret
```

I'm going to assume you have no knowledge of assembly -- but don't worry, this example isn't terribly hard to keep up with.  What's happening here is that we `call scanf`, and we `compare` the result of it (`i`) with 8.

Next, there's a `J`ump if `N`ot `E`qual instruction to the label L2.  This means that if `i` is equal to 8, the following instructions executed are:

- Move 3 into  `rbp`
- Move `rbp` into `eax`
- Leave (thereby returning the value 3 from the program).

However, if `i` is **not** equal to 8, then when we hit the `jne` instruction, we don't jump.  Instead, we:

- Move 100 into `rbp`
- `J`u`mp` unconditionally to the label L4
- Move `rbp` into `eax` and end up returning 100 from the program.

With the assembly generated here, there are really only two possible branches.  You can't arbitrarily reorder the code.

So would it be possible to execute both branches (when they aren't both `return` statements)?  Yes, on the condition that your compiler is incapable of correctly producing branching code.  But that would never happen on a production-level compiler.

Comment: I note that in your example, there is no side-effect on the return statements. The compiler would avoid doing such "compute A ; r <- A ; compute B ; r<-B ; ret" path when A and B cannot be reduced to side-effect-free expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
if (//some condition//)
{ 
    IF:{
    printf("Hello "); //Code for if block.
     } 
    goto ELSE;
} 
else
{  
    goto IF;
    ELSE:{
      printf("world");//code for else block.
         }
}
return 0; 
}
```

Output: `Hello world`

Answer (score 0):

Without devious trickery, no, this is not possible.  Consider what the expression means:

```
if (cond) {
  ifTrue;
} else {
  ifFalse;
}
```

This says to execute `ifTrue` if `cond` is true (a non-zero value/`true`), and to execute `ifFalse` if `cond` is false (zero/`false`).  Since `cond` can't be simultaneously true and false, you can't execute both `ifTrue` and `ifFalse` without a special case, such as `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integer as test variable and check its value using >,<,>=,<=,==

```
    int x = 0;

    if ( x >= 0 ) {
        statement 1;
    }
    if ( x <= 0 ) {
        statement 2;
    }
```

In this example, both statements are only executed if x is 0. Otherwise only one of them will be.

Comment: We are talking about if, else not if , if

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... 7 years, later.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a trick question, you could answer with

```
if( ({ statement2; 1; }) ) 
  statement1;
else
  statement2;
```

Using GCC statement expressions :) For expression statements, there is the comma operator

```
if(expr2, 1) 
  expr1;
else
  expr2;
```

This is a [quite popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199/whats-the-condition-in-c-interview-question).

Answer (score 0):

There is no *single* value for `x` for which all paths of a conditional statement will be executed (which is kind of the *point* of a conditional statement; you want to execute one branch *or* the other based on `x`).

However...

In C (and C++), you could use the `setjmp`/`longjmp` facility to execute both paths of an `if`-`else`:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jmp_buf Env;

int main(void)
{
  int status = setjmp(Env);
  if (status == 0)
  {
    printf("In status == 0 branch\n");
    longjmp(Env,1);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("In status != 0 branch\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The initial call to `setjmp` returns 0, so the first branch is taken.  The call to `longjmp` unwinds the stack back to the point where the `setjmp` call returns, but this time the return value is 1 (the second argument to `longjmp`), so the second branch is taken.  However, this is *not* the same thing as `status` evaluating to 0 and non-0 simultaneously.

In practice, it's similar to writing

```
for (status = 0; status < 2; status++)
{
  if (status == 0)
    printf("In status == 0 branch\n");
  else
    printf("In status != 0 branch\n");
}
```

although the semantics are different.

You could probably do something similarly ugly in C++ with exceptions, but I'm not enough of a C++ expert to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ( x ) {
default: // if ( x )
  // stuff
  // no break
case 0: // else
  // more stuff
  break;
}
```

or the much simpler

```
if ( x ) {
  // stuff
}
// more stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

except `goto` you can use `ucontext` or `setjmp/longjump`.

1. you can use `ucontext` to switch the execute flow.
   for example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void func(void);

int  x = 0;
ucontext_t context, *cp = &context;

int main(void) {

  getcontext(cp);


  if (x == 0) {
    printf("hello\n");
    func();
  } else {
    printf("world\n");
  }

}

void func(void) {
  x++;
  setcontext(cp);
}
```

output:

```
hello
world
```

2. you can also use `setjmp/longjmp`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int main()
{
    jmp_buf buf;

    if (setjmp(buf) != 0)
    {
        printf("world\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("hello\n");
        longjmp(buf, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    x = 6;
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        printf("Divisible by two\n");
    }
    else if (x % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Divisible by three\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not divisible by two or three\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
Divisible by two
```

**NOT**

```
Divisible by two
Divisible by three
```