# Is it possible to execute both if and else part of an if --- else control statement?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simultaneous execution of both if and else blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031610/if-elses-simultaneous-execution-in-c-or-c)

Is it possible to put some condition, so that both if and else part in an if ...else control statement can be executed without any warning or error ??

Comment: I would hope not; and its a NO in all the languages I know.

Comment: Wouldn't that undo the purpose of an if-else?

Comment: Try and describe what your actual problem is instead, seems like its a solution looking for a problem at the moment.

Comment: umm..don't write the `if` condition in the first place.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? Clearly this is not a party-game you're asking for so there has to be some kind of problem you want to solve? What is that problem? If you tell us about that, we might be able to give you usable answers.

Comment: You could try a switch statement without the "break"'s :-)

Comment: I think I've seen this come up at least one other time. It isn't easy to search for, even here, because both "if" and "else" appear to be stop words in the search engine.

Answer (score 26):

**Do not use! ;-)**

Yes, by `fork`ing.

```
if ( fork() ) {
    printf("if\n");
}
else {
    printf("else\n");
}
```

There are no real use cases to prefer the above code, unless it is for parallel execution.

Comment: Smart but this just confuses the issue.

Comment: +1 Impressive ... but I don't know if it's a good or a bad impression :)

Comment: +1 creative thinking; - a trillion because many people will implement it now ;-)

Comment: It's an ingenious way to answer the question (so +1) but doesn't it make you feel dirty all over?

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box; the question does not ask for a way to execute both branches *in the same process*.

Comment: I tried the ridiculous fork() solution, ie. raising another process/thread, but it did not link on either my Windows box or ARM embedded systems, so I'm downvoting.

Comment: Martin James: You are wrong. I will not tell you how to run `fork()` on Windows. It is your assignment and your problem to solve.

Answer (score 9):

No, there's no way to write a Schrödinger if clause.

You might be able to execute both with a goto, but it would never pass a code review.

Comment: +1. Execute 0.4 of the first branch and 0.6 of the second one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define else if (1)
int main(void)
{
    int test = 1;

    if (test == 1)
    {
        printf("if\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("else\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
#undef else
```

A note for newbies: Never do this in real life! Instead, think about your problem again...

What you probably wanted is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int one_condition = 1;
    int other_condition = 2;

    if ((one_condition == 1) || (other_condition == 2))
    {
        printf("if\n");
    }

    if ((one_condition != 1) || (other_condition == 2))
    {
        printf("quasi-else\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can replace the else-path by having another if-clause with negated conditions. This gives you the possibility to override it with a second condition.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not possible (inside the same process).

Comment: Other answers suggest that it's possible, with a `goto` or with a `#define else if (1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've misunderstood your problem.

If you want a code block to execute regardless of the condition, take it out of the if...else statement.

```
void foofunc(int n)
{
     a = 44*n;
     if(a == 484)
     {
        //do something
     }
     else
     {
        //do something if a DOES NOT equal 484
     }

     //do something regardless of the outcome of the test.
}
```

In this example, ridiculous though it is, the last line is outside the condition statement, so will execute whether a == 484 or not, which seems to me to be the same as making c trigger your `else` block regardless of the `if` test succeeds.

Of course, else blocks are not mandatory, so if you don't care what happens if your condition fails, then simply don't have an else block.

```
void foofunc(int n)
{
     a = 44*n;
     if(a == 484)
     {
        //do something
     }

     //do something regardless of the outcome of the test.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to have both branches of this sort of statement execute?

```
Dim X As Boolean
X = False
If X = True Then
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

You *could* get it to execute using GoTo ... but that goes against good programming practice.

```
Dim X As Boolean
X = False
If X = True Then
    ...
    Goto ElseStuff
Else
    ElseStuff:
    ...
End If
```

Instead of that you should write separate procedures / functions to accomplish the behavior you'd like to have execute in both statements ... or simply put the code which should execute in all cases **outside** of the If block.

That would be functionally equivalent to using the GoTo, plus it makes it clear to anybody else.

Comment: I would say that this goes against ... EVERYTHING ... not only goodp programming practice ;-)