# Executing both 'If' as well as 'else' block

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Stupid Question Regarding If-Else's Simultaneous Execution in C++ or C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031610/stupid-question-regarding-if-elses-simultaneous-execution-in-c-or-c)
>   [Is it possble to execute both if  and else part of an if — else control statement ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837858/is-it-possble-to-execute-both-if-and-else-part-of-an-if-else-control-stateme)

Hello everyone..
I had a question in an interview like this which i couldn't answer.
Consider Following code block.
Assume necessary header files.

```
if(.......)
{
    printf("hello");
}
else
{
    printf("world");
}
```

without moving/adding any code & without use of additional printing statements bring output as "Hello world"..You have to write the missing condition in if statement..
is it possible to execute both blocks by some condition?? Please help

Comment: @Steve there was a nice suggestion with `setjump()`. It's possible that they expected that solution. I'm not sure, but will a forked process print to the same console?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the other questions.  The OP simply put the wrong title on the question.  It does NOT ask you to execute the if and else, it simply asks you to insert a condition that generates the requested output.  My solution is below.

Comment: @Larry: I assumed that was a mistake in the question that allows your answer. It says, "without use of additional printing statements", which I took to include calls to `printf`, whether they're statements or just expressions. Also the text "is it possible to execute both blocks by some condition" *is* a dupe. As against that, making this a completely different question, the requested output is "Hello world" (note capital H and space), suggesting that the first block should *not* be executed. Also the `fork()` solution doesn't order the blocks, they could run in either order or simultaneously.

Comment: I can't answer this question any more, but I want to!!  If you abuse some little used C syntax you can do it without vfork.  `if(fork() ? (sleep(1), 0) : 1) {`.  The sleep ensures the correct order.

Comment: if ( fork() ) {
    printf("hello");
}
else {
    printf("world");
}

Comment: I tried the ridiculous fork() solution, ie. raising another process/thread, but it did not link on either my Windows box or ARM embedded systems, so I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 37):

This will work

```
if(schrodingers_cat_is_dead())
{
    printf("hello");
}
else
{
    printf("world");
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as you look at the output, not only will it collapse into the state of only producing "hello" or "world", but there's a 50% chance you will have murdered a cat.

Comment: Would the down voter please explain why they do not have a sense of humour?

Answer (score 34):

try [`fork()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fork.html) ! (and join afterwards). That's the only feature involving quantum mechanics that I know of.

`fork()` returns two distinct values at a time, which only the Schrödinger's cat is capable of.

**NOTE:** In a comment, Donal Fellows suggests:

> You'll get more reliable behavior with [`!vfork()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/vfork.html)

Comment: ...and hope they print in the right order.

Comment: Wouldn't that be terrible programming practice? Why would they expect someone to know (let alone do) that in an interview? :/

Comment: I think they expect people to be imaginative…

Comment: ah, I get why it works that way. Had to research fork :) the child pid is zero and the parent is some number. Interesting trick. If you were a C programmer familiar with multithreading, it might/should come easier to you.

Comment: @townsean: this is a great code to do fork, that way you make the father do one thing while the son is doing another. if the if was if (0 == fork()) it would do diffrent things for diffrent threads, and that is very desireable, for example if you want to execute an external process, and make the father wait till it finish.

Comment: You'll get more reliable behavior with `!vfork()`

Comment: even better: `if (!vfork() || sleep(100))` should ensure correct order

Comment: No, `!vfork()` is enough; it's a tricky feature of vfork() that it suspends the parent until the child does execve() or exit().

Comment: @none: ah, interesting. I can see it being very useful in that context. Thanks!

Comment: `vfork` is not reliable; in fact, `vfork` may simply be implemented as `fork`. Instead you need to use `fork` and `wait` to ensure synchronization.

Comment: “Ensure synchronization” is for wimps.

Comment: With `fork` and `wait` you can get this to work reliably: http://ideone.com/1mtsR

Answer (score 16):

If you can put in a macro definition as "part" of that condition...

```
if (1
#define else if (1)
)
{
    printf("hello");
}
else
{
    printf("world");
}
```

Then that code will indeed print "`helloworld`". It's a horrible, dirty trick though; my soul is probably in trouble for mentioning it!

Comment: Yeah, that's great too :) Don't forget to `#undef` it. I think you could just `#define else`. It will just scope the `printf("world");`.

Comment: this will do : `if(1) {printf("hello");} if(1) {printf("world");}`

Comment: thanks Donal.....It's Ok....But it doesn't make any sense...Though it achieves the intended aim very well. lets say " by Hook or by CROOK!!"

Comment: @Prashant: Sense?! You're getting deep voodoo hackery tricks here, not good structured programming. :-)

Comment: I like this one. Not expected.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the exact phrasing of the question.  As you describe it, the question *does not* ask you to execute both branches of the if statement.  It asks you to insert a condition that results in printing "hello world" without changing anything else.

If you have complete freedom in what you put in the condition, you can use this solution:

```
 if(printf("hello ") == -1)
 {
     printf("hello");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("world");
 }
```

However, the solution uses "printf" in the condition, which is ruled out by one of the rules you gave.  What's not clear to me is whether the printf prohibition also applies to what you write in the condition.

**Note: Answer is edited to reflect the comments.  The original answer ignored the prohibition on print statements.**

Comment: `..without moving/adding any code & without use of additional printing statements bring output as "Hello world"..` So, this does not meet requirements.

Comment: The problem is… the question asks for no additional printing statements. While you could try arguing before the judge that the `printf` you inserted is a printing expression (tricky!) I suspect it's not going to get you credit. Nice try though.

Comment: Well, you guys may well be right depending on the original phraseology of the question.  If you're allowed to enter anything you want in the condition (and the prohibition on adding code only applies outside the condition) then the solution stands.  But if the prohibition applies inside the condition as well, obviously my solution is invalid.

Comment: I tryed in php it will success

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it's probably bad practice.  Seems the interviewer was testing your knowledge of the language.  Built with gcc 4.1.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  if(!printf("hello ")) {
    printf("hello");
  } else {
    printf("world");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tell How....It will add to my knowledge ..:-)

Answer (score 3):

There is one possible way, it is not recommended.

```
if(check==true)
{
 printf("dont do this");
 goto condition1;
}
else
{
 condition1: ////this is crazy
 printf("Dont do this ever");
}
```

Comment: +1 for warped thinking, but it fails the "without moving/adding any code" constraint?

Comment: You *cheated*! no way you can put anything inside the `{}` blocks according to the question :)

Comment: You're right I did cheat, no soup for me. This question is pretty insane

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Either the first block or the else block will get executed; that is the nature of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to execute both branches of an if/else without exploiting it with weird things. If a condition is true then the else won't get executed and viceversa.

They're absolutely mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Not without iterating over it again.  I don't think you can do any Duff device like craziness in if statements.  I suppose you could use goto, you say just by writing the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In a debugger you could step through the if block, then move execution to the else block to execute, but that's just a silly answer to what seems to me to be a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think is this:

```
//if(.......)
{
    printf("hello");
}
//else
{
    printf("world");
}
```

Comment: `else` can't exists without `if`.

Comment: This question states `.You have to write the missing condition in if statement.. `

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
if (!printf("hello")){
   printf("hello");
}
else{
   printf(" world");
}
```

Comment: Have you read the conditions? `without moving/adding any code & without use of additional printing statements bring output as "Hello world"..`

Comment: ...so much for my first answer here :)

Answer (score -1):

you could try :

```
if()
{
printf("hello");
goto Found;
}
else
{
Found: printf("world");
}
```