# Condition that is true and false at the same time in C or Java

Tags: java, c, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the “condition” in C interview question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199/whats-the-condition-in-c-interview-question)

Can something like this be done?

Code:

```
if(condition) {
    printf("Hello")
} else {
    printf("World");
}
```

Result: **Hello World**

What should be **the condition** to be used to make that possible ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your compiler compiled that code, your VM would print "Hello World" of course.

Comment: No, and you're missing a close brace after ... else{ printf("World")  }  ;

Comment: This is probably the third time i've seen this question in a month.

Comment: This is one of the top 3 *stupidest* interview questions I've seen (the others being "how do you change the value of a `const`-qualified variable" and "how do you do _______ without using a _______ control structure?")  If you are seriously asked this question in an interview, *run away*; you do not want to work there.

Answer (score 7):

No.

The `else` statement will *only* execute if the `if` didn't.

Comment: There are some cheats down here, but this should be the only correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can cheat to get this result in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define else printf(" ");

int main()
{
    int condition = 1;
    if(condition) { 
        printf("Hello");
    } 
    else { 
        printf("World");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: That's nasty, dirty, bad voodoo.  Not something you'd want to do in production.  But it is a working answer.

Comment: Is this really legal C? I know that the C++ standard forbids the redefinition of keybords even if it works with most compilers.

Comment: @DaVinci: To the best of my knowledge this is valid C. In C, you are not allowed to define a macro with a name lexically identical to a keyword before you include a standard library header.  As long as you define the macro after all of the Standard Library header includes, you should be good to go.  (C++ has the more stringent rule that you cannot define a macro with a name lexically identical to a keyword anywhere in any translation unit that includes any standard library header).

Comment: Huh? How the hell does that work? ... Oh, OK I just saw it Mr Smarty Pants, you should at least explain and point out that you've defined "else" as a macro at the top of the file, which overrides the normal usage of "else", and prints out a space instead. This answer is bound to confuse new users, so I'd suggest showing the expanded version with the "else" replaced below the original version.

Comment: +1 for the "insanity" as described by someone else.

Comment: If this confuses anyone after they actually see the #define, then they shouldn't ever, ever, ever, be looking at this code in the first place

Answer (score 3):

The only idea that comes into my mind is something like

```
if (printf("Hello") > 0)
  printf("");
else
  printf(" world");
```

but it's not the same thing, you can't execute both branches of an if/else: one of two is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

The instructor is expecting you to fill in `fork()` as the *condition*. This is not general C code but Unix/POSIX code, and works by splitting the process into a parent process and child process. `fork` returns the child process id (a nonzero number, thus *true*) in the parent and 0 (*false*) in the child.

Another potential way to solve the problem, if you can add code elsewhere, is to write `setjmp(jmp_buf)` as the *condition*, and add a `longjmp(jmp_buf, 1);` after the conditional. However this seems to break the rules of the problem.

Comment: Of course, to definitely get `HelloWorld` as the output, you need to use `!fork() || wait() && 0` as the condition.

Answer (score 1):

if/elses are either/ors. Either the if portion is executed or the else, but never both.

Answer (score 1):

No, the statement is `if` ... `else`, not `if` ... `and then also maybe`.  The condition is evaluated *once*, and the branch is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, it's not possible.  The way the if/else is translated to Java bytecode (and in either case, to machine code), one process will run exactly one of the two branches of the statement.  If we didn't have if/else, we'd end up using `goto` to synthesize it, and that would look a lot like this:

```
  if (condition) goto if_block;

else_block:
  printf("World");
  goto after_ifelse;

if_block:
  printf("Hello");

after_ifelse:
```

As you can see, if the condition's true (even if it could somehow also be false!), the process will follow the 'if' branch *and skip past the other*.  There's no way to get around this in a single process; any way would require changing the code of the program, or broken hardware (particularly RAM or CPU), or enough radiation to kill you.  And every compiler and environment i know of treats `if/else` that way, though it's common to have the `else` case after the `if` (and invert the condition), which makes the (quite valid) assumption that any boolean condition that's not true is false.

Now with all that said...in C, it's semi possible, but not in the way you're thinking -- and not on every OS.  On *nix systems, there's a system call usually called `fork()`, which allows one process to become two (thereby sidestepping the "one process will run exactly one branch" limitation).

```
if (fork())
    printf("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

But (1) this code has an inherent race condition -- both branches are now set to run, but either one could run before the other.  You'd need to `wait` on the child process.  And (2) this isn't a "condition", it's a function call.  If you're not allowed to add code, then this should not be available as an answer.

Or you could do some evil macro stuff to translate the `else` into something else entirely.  But anyone reading your code later would want to hunt you down and confiscate your keyboard, and that's if they're nice.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean type variables in both languages do *not* allow what you want to do.  The whole point is that they must be one or the other.

To accomplish what you want, you probably need a custom type.

```
//This type allows for quantum weirdness
public class NotABool{

    public boolean isTrue = false;
    public boolean isFalse = false;

    //Funky setMethod
    void set(boolean value){
       //...
    }
}
```

```
NotABool nab = new NotABool();

if (NotABool.isTrue){
   //Print "Hello"
}
if (NotABool.isFalse){
   //Print "World"
}
```

Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: ok I see. It's just that I was told by my teacher that something like I asked was possible, using a single condition.

Comment: , but I must find the way to do that. Thanks for the answer. Sorry for my english :p

Comment: @lucas It should not be possible in either language.  Can you write misleading code that makes it look like it is? `yes.`  Might there be compiler bugs out there that allow this? `unlikely.`  Is this intended to be allowed? `Definitely not.`

Comment: @Lucas: Your teacher is doing you a horrible disservice.  Where it is possible, it's due either to compiler bugs or platform-specific details like `fork()`, or other sneaky tricks that have no place in a classroom.  If he's teaching you to write *nix code, then he should have phrased the question/problem differently; as it is, it just sounds like he's some hack that doesn't understand the purpose of if/else.

Comment: +1 to `he's doing you a disservice`

Answer (score 0):

Its insane, but:

```
int test = 0;
String s = "";

switch (test) {
    case 0: s += "Hello";
    default: s += "World";
}

System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: No.   James' answer is insane.  Yours isn't.

Comment: bool -> int conversion (considering 0 is True :)) for this purpose is quite extravagant.. at least; but thanks :)

Comment: This isn't insane at all, but it is not at all what the question is asking. You don't use if/else at all.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are describing looks more like the `switch` structures.

In Java, you can only switch on `int` and `enum` types, but in C, you can switch on string as well as `int` types.

It would look like so:

```
int i = 0;

switch (i) {
    case 0:
         System.out.print("Hello ");
    case 1:
         System.out.print("World!");
         break;
  }
```

The resulting output would be "Hello World!"

When `i` is `0`, it matches the first case and executes the code until the next `break;` statement is found. If `i` was `1`, it would only print out "World!".